# CSS/NodeJS: Refreshing userslist weird position

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I am now working on a chat with NodeJS but now have I a weird problem, when somebody joins the chat:

[image: this is good]

But when you join the chat or somebody disconnect or connect something weird happens:

[image: this is not good]

The userslist seems to move 1 pixel. Can you see on the top and right a thick line? Why has this happened?

Nothing on the code changes, as far as I can see, when I 'refresh' the userlist:

```
socket.on('refreshUsers', function(refreshData) {
    var users_html = "<div id=\"userList\"><ul class=\"users\"><div class=\"scroll-pane\">";
    console.log("Refreshing users...");
    
    refreshData.users.forEach(function(data) {
            users_html += "<li><img src=\"./pic/"+ data.pic +"\">"+ data.username +"</li>";
        });
    
    users_html += "</ul></div></div>";
    
    $( "#userList" ).html(users_html);
});
```

When I load the userlist (so when you not joining):

```
function buildChat() {
    console.log("Build chat...");
    $( "#container" ).fadeOut(0);
    var rooms_html = "<div class=\"head\"><select name=\"rooms\">";
    var users_html = "<div id=\"userList\"><ul class=\"users\"><div class=\"scroll-pane\">";
    var chatBox = "<div id=\"chatBox\"></div>";
    var messagesBoard = "<div id=\"messagesBoard\"><div id=\"messagesHead\">UBB | Emotions | Help</div><textarea id=\"message\" placeholder=\"Typ hier om te chatten\"></textarea></div>";
    socket.on('startChatInfo', function(chatInfo) {
    
        console.log("Loading rooms...");
        chatInfo.rooms.forEach(function(data) {
            rooms_html += "<option>"+ data.from +" &raquo "+ data.name +"</option>";
        });
        rooms_html += "</select></div>";
    
        console.log("Loading users");
        chatInfo.users.forEach(function(data) {
            users_html += "<li><img src=\"./pic/"+ data.pic +"\">"+ data.username +"</li>";
        });
        
        users_html += "</ul></div></div>";
        
    
        $( "#container" ).html(rooms_html + users_html + chatBox + messagesBoard);
        $( "#container" ).fadeIn(1000);
    });
    
}
```

And here's the CSS, which is the same, whether I load the users or refresh:

```
#userList {
    margin:0px;
    width:228px;
    height:355px;
    float:right;
    border:1px solid #cccccc;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.users li {
    list-style-type:none;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
    line-height:50px;
    padding-left:7px;
}

.users li:hover {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    cursor:pointer;
}

ul {
    padding:0px;
}

.scroll-pane {
    width: 100%;
    height: 355px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

And of course the HTML:

```
<div id="userList"><ul class="users"><div class="scroll-pane"><li><img src="./pic/none.png">Anne</li><li><img src="./pic/none.png">Dylan</li><li><img src="./pic/none.png">lennard</li><li><img src="./pic/none.png">Mackie</li></div></ul></div>
```

Demo URL: http://apps.jreitsma.eu:3101/

To join the chat, typ in the console:

```
socket.emit('requestUsername', { value: 'hereyourname' });
```

May you need to log in on 2 tabs with diffrent usernames to see it!
I have really no idea why this is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: An `UL` can _only_ have `LI` as children, not `DIV`. Correct the faulty HTML you are creating.

Comment: Fixed it, but not the main problem.

Comment: Well then show us an online example (or do you expect anyone to re-build your system themselves to see your error?)

Comment: Well, I don`t know how to demo this? I have no VPS or something like that.

Comment: Demo:  http://apps.jreitsma.eu:3101/

Answer (score 0):

You're placing a div with the same id in the #userList div..
Change the refresh user function to the following:

```
socket.on('refreshUsers', function(refreshData) {
    var users_html = "<div class=\"scroll-pane\"><ul class=\"users\">";
    console.log("Refreshing users...");

    refreshData.users.forEach(function(data) {
        users_html += "<li><img src=\"./pic/"+ data.pic +"\">"+ data.username +"</li>";
    });

    users_html += "</ul></div>";

    $( "#userList" ).html(users_html);
});
```